# Aws Code Deploy Session error while deploying application stored in github

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a sample application stored in github. I want to deploy it to an ec2 instance that is already up and running. I did the below steps in the AWS console and I get this error:

> "There seems to be a problem with your session. Please try again in a
>   few minutes or login again. If the problem persists try clearing your
>   browser cookies."

No matter what I do, I cannot get rid of this issue. I have tried clearing my cookies, using another browser, restarting my browsers and system. Nothing happened.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Created an application and a deployment group "Development"
2. Tried to deploy a new revision. (Image 1)
3. To connect github and aws, entered my github credentials.
4. Got the error. (Image 2)

## **Image1**

[image]

## **Image2**

[image]

Comment: Today, for no apparent reason, the connection with AWS and github seems to run okay. I had no problems and the connection was successful. Since I did nothing fancy, it must be AWS internal error which they solved yesterday. Hence this question becomes invalid for this platform. Sorry for posting it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We got this as well, contacted support, and received the following (working) workaround.

> This appears to be an issue in the way GitHub is redirecting back to the AWS console. The CodeDeploy and AWS Console team have been made aware of this and are working to have it resolved. In the meantime, the workaround is to clear your cookies, change region in the console to N. Virginia (US East) and back to the region you are working in, then connect CodeDeploy to GitHub again.
>
> To detail the steps:
>
> 1. Clear your browser cache
> 2. Visit https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com and sign in
> 3. Change the region in the top left corner to 'N. Virginia'
> 4. Change the region back to 'Oregon'
> 5. Open the CodeDeploy console and reconnect an app with GitHub
> 6. Sign into Github account